Locale not setting in Laravel 11 with Inertia.js
I am trying to set app locale in Laravel 11 with Inertia.js.
Here is the links to set locale:
<DropdownLink :href="route('set-language', { lang: 'lv' })">
    <div class="flex items-center">
         <img src="../../images/icons/latvian.png" :alt="$t('locales.lv')" height="25px" width="25px">
         <span class="ml-2">{{ $t('locales.lv') }}</span>
   </div>
</DropdownLink>

<DropdownLink :href="route('set-language', { lang: 'en' })">
    <div class="flex items-center">
          <img src="../../images/icons/english.png" :alt="$t('locales.en')" height="25px" width="25px">
           <span class="ml-2">{{ $t('locales.en') }}</span>
    </div>
</DropdownLink>

Controller action:
public function setLanguage(string $lang)
{
   Session::put('language', $lang);

   return Inertia::location(url()->previous());
}

Middleware (added to controller's action route):
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
   if (Session::has('language')){
       App::setLocale(Session::get('language'));
   }

   return $next($request)
       ->withCookie(
            cookie()->forever(
                'language',
                 Session::has('language') ? Session::get('language') : 'lv',
                 null,
                 null,
                 null,
                 false
              )
         );
}

App starting point:
const getLocale = (localeCookie) => {
    const localeName = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + localeCookie + '=([^;]+)'));

    return localeName
        ? localeName[2]
        : 'lv';
};

const locale = getLocale('language');

const i18n = setupI18n({locale});
loadLocaleMessages(i18n, locale);
const { t } = i18n.global;

The problem is that locale in laravel is not setting. I have dd() app locale and it's correct but in application it still remains 'en'.
So in my language selector where I conditionally show language flag, it's always showing english flag.
<div class="flex items-center"> 
   <img v-if="$page.props.locale === 'en'" src="../../images/icons/english.png" :alt="$t('locales.en')" height="25px" width="25px">
   <img v-if="$page.props.locale === 'lv'" src="../../images/icons/latvian.png" :alt="$t('locales.lv')" height="25px" width="25px">
</div>

Here is how I get app locale (Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php)
public function share(Request $request): array
{
   return [
       ...parent::share($request),
       'auth' => [
            'user' => $request->user(),
        ],
        'appTitle' => config('app.name'),
         'locale' => App::currentLocale(),
    ];
}


Resolved the issue.
In Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php
public function share(Request $request): array
{
   return [
       ...parent::share($request),
       'auth' => [
            'user' => $request->user(),
        ],
        'appTitle' => config('app.name'),
         'locale' => Session::has('language') 
                ? Session::get('language') 
                : App::getLocale(),
     ];
}


In your JavaScript code, you're trying to retrieve the language from a cookie. But it seems like maybe that part isn't working quite as expected. Maybe the cookie isn't being set properly when the user changes languages, or maybe it's not being read correctly by your JavaScript.
So, when you change the language, check if the session is indeed storing the chosen language.
Add dd(Session::get('language')) in your controller action right after setting the language.
Then check if the cookie is being set correctly when you change the language.
Add console.log(document.cookie) in your JavaScript function that retrieves the locale from the cookie.
If both of these steps seem to be working fine, then the issue might be with how you're handling the language in your JavaScript setup. Ensure that the locale retrieved from the cookie is being passed correctly to your frontend framework and that it's being used to display the correct language flag.

Did all the steps and everything is working as expected. Forgot to tell that I display flag by locale returned by Inertia.
